# My bank refused to do a charge back

Tags: credit-card, chargeback

Once I got mis-charged on my bank-issued debit/credit card.

What happened is that a COMCAST service representative offered to connect me with "premium" technical support for $50, so I said OK, then she disconnected me instead of transferring me to the technical support. I tried calling back, but after 45 minutes of waiting I gave up. Nevertheless, I was still billed the $50. Naturally, I wanted to do a chargeback to get refunded.

I went to my bank in person to demand the charge back, but they told me to "work it out"  with the vendor, ie COMCAST, and refused to do the charge back. I do not want to call COMCAST again because the wait times are very long and I doubt they would cooperate with me anyway.

How can I make my bank do the charge back, or should I talk to somebody else (attorney general's office, etc)?

I live in Massachusetts.

Comment: You accepted the terms proposed by the bank when they issued you the debit/credit card. What does your Card Agreement say your "rights" are in this case? Unless the Card Agreement is especially anti-consumer and contrary to some aspect of contract law, I doubt the attorney-general's office can help.

Comment: Your first mistake was choosing service with Comcast.  Your second was paying extra for them to fix their service.  That said it should be similar to disputing a credit card charge, but you need to attempt to work things out with Comcast in good faith first.

Answer (score 9):

Call Comcast during a non-peak time (first thing in the morning?), wait on hold, and politely explain what happened and request a $50 credit. Also politely request that your premium support request be handled for free given how much hassle you've had getting disconnected.

They'll be able to tell your premium request was never answered because there are no notes on your support tickets.

Calling them is much easier than any of your other options.

Comment: I already explained that attempting to call them involves long wait times, over an hour in many cases.

Comment: Any other option will take far longer than an hour or two and will have less chance of success. If you can't get a chargeback, you have to go back to the vendor. Suing them would take a lot more effort and expense, don't you think?

Comment: I just want a charge back. Why is this complicated? You sound like my banker. Should I sue my banker? I mean what is the problem here?

Comment: @TylerDurden that is one of the main reasons I *never* use debit cards. It would be much easier with credit cards (as it would be their money at stake). In any case, if the bank refuses to do the charge back your only resort (other than what Rocky suggested) would be to sue Comcast.

Comment: @TylerDurden In addition to what Rocky has said; your successfully doing a chargeback won't change the fact that Comcast thinks you owe them $50 for premium support.  Unless you settle the issue with them, they'll go though their process for when a customer doesn't pay his bill; which will likely escalate from late charges to termination and selling the original $50 fee + all the late fees they've applied to a bill collector.

Comment: Sorry @FiveBagger but we are really trying to help you. If that is not the answer you want, then I'm sorry but it means we are out of pixie dust.

Answer (score 2):

You can't **make** your bank do a charge back. This function is to assist with straight up fraud, not a customer service mistake. (Think spoofed or stolen card or if a vendor intentionally acted fraudulently.) While you may believe what they did is fraud, your bank will require that you provide the vendor with the opportunity to rectify the situation themselves. Trying to call back and giving up after a long hold time won't meet their standards. If banks started letting anyone unhappy with a vendor start doing charge backs, they would be doing nothing else all day. The issues you're describing has not reached the threshold for the bank to authorize a charge back.

Comcast has local and regional offices, and you could go in person to speak with someone. Maybe there isn't one near you. There are non-peak hours which wait times will be less. You'll just have to grin and bear it if you truly want the money back. Then, take your business elsewhere and post bad reviews online. Always keep in mind that when you eventually speak with someone, they will not be the person that messed up, and you should be overly nice and polite to them. I promise it will yield far better results than being surly and demanding.

Another way to get Comcast's attention would be to file a complaint with the BBB. It might take longer, but I've had this work with big companies, usually with good results. Again, be nice to whomever contacts you.

In reference to your recent duplicate question: Mastercard won't be able to help at all. They play no part in the transaction at all.