# Bank refuses to do charge back

Tags: credit-card

I had a bogus charge on my credit card. I called a COMCAST help line and asked for "premium" support ($50) to try to solve the problem with my internet quickly. The help center took my credit card info and charged it, then disconnected me without helping me.

I went to my bank and told them I wanted to do a charge back on the card for $50 and they refused to do it.

What is my recourse here? Should I call the card issuer (Mastercard) and tell them the bank is refusing to do a charge back?

Comment: It sounds like you think you have an absolute right to charge back any transaction; but you don't, as you'll find out if you read your card agreement.  You can only charge back a transaction under certain specified conditions, and it's up to you to convince the bank that those conditions apply.  Apparently you haven't done that to their satisfaction; maybe you haven't even tried.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question a while ago? Is this a duplicate or did you do the same thing again? http://money.stackexchange.com/q/41652/30798

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot I asked the question before.

Comment: Is this for the same situation? You definitely won't win a charge back request from 2014.

Comment: BTW, it isn't a "bogus" charge if you authorized Comcast to charge for the call -- It's a different matter altogether if you say they didn't deliver on what you paid for, and ***that*** is why your bank is balking.  You have to show how you didn't get what *you* authorized a transaction for.  That'll require you trying to work it out with Comcast first, but if you refuse to call them then there's little the bank will do about it.  You *did* authorize the charge, so it's legitimate.  You didn't get what you paid for.  THAT is your real issue.

Comment: The chargeback just protects the bank. If they don't do the chargeback, that means they're just willing to take the risk that you will refuse to pay them rather than the merchant. Whether or not the bank does a chargeback, if you dispute the validity of the charge, *you do not pay it*, period.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How can I "not pay it". The bank debited it from my account already.

Comment: @FiveBagger You specifically said in your question that it was a credit card. The rules for chargebacks on debit cards are *completely* different.

Answer (score 7):

You need to know what your bank's dispute procedures are, to begin with.  I would be very surprised if a bank were to just flat out refuse to open a charge dispute for no reason.  Is it possible you didn't go about it the right way?  *I'm not saying you did anything wrong*, but each bank/card issuer has a set of procedures for how charge disputes are handled, and if you didn't follow them properly, they are unlikely to help you.  That being said, if my bank was that unhelpful, I'd be looking for a new one!

The other aspect to consider is talking to Comcast about the issue to see if maybe they'll do a bill credit if they aren't willing to refund your card.  That's always an option.  Comcast should be able to investigate the incident and (if the call was recorded, which it usually is) make it right with you.

In any event, make sure you document everything you do (when you called, who you talked to, what the conversation was) so that if you have to go further with this then you have proof you made good faith efforts to resolve it.

My experience with Comcast (*and I'm only speaking for myself here!*) has been that they're generally pretty good at resolving issues, including sending a tech to my house on July 4th within an hour of my call at no charge for an issue with my Internet.

Start with talking to Comcast.  Keep your cool, and if you feel you aren't getting anywhere with the agent you speak to, don't hesitate to ask for a supervisor.  The same is true with your bank.  Ask to escalate the issue to someone higher up the food chain, because they have the power to do something for you.  But I can't emphasize enough that ***you have to keep your calm***.  If you go off the deep end then whoever you're talking to is much less likely to *want* to help you or go out of their way to do something.  Remember, *they* aren't the one who made the mistake, but they *are* the one who can do something about it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I do not want to talk with COMCAST. COMCAST has 1+ hour hold times. The whole reason I paid the $50 in the first place was so that I could "talk" to them. I am not going to pay another $50 to try to get them to refund the last $50 I paid them. The question is how to deal with my bank's refusal to issue the charge back. I don't really care what the bank's procedures are. I demanded to do a charge back and the bank officer refused to do it.

Comment: @FiveBagger: You **have** to care what the bank's procedures are.  They're the only ones who have the power to do what you are trying to do.  If you don't follow their procedures you'll get nowhere.

Comment: I have Comcast, and they don't charge me just to call customer service -- ***ever***.  They may charge me for technical help if the situation calls for it, but never just to call and ask for general assistance.  Call, ask for a supervisor, and **calmly** explain the situation.  Document it, as I suggested, so if they do nothing, now you can go to your bank with evidence you at least tried.  Calling MasterCard won't help.  They just license the bank to issue their cards.  They don't get involved in merchant/bank disputes.  Calling Comcast is the fastest way to solve this.